# Compute Christoffel symbol of $\mathbb S^2$.

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $$(x,y,z)=f(\theta,\gamma )=(\sin \varphi\cos\theta,\sin\varphi\sin\theta,\cos \varphi).$$

Therefore,
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}=(-\sin\varphi\sin\theta,\sin\varphi\cos\theta,0)$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \varphi}=(\cos\varphi\cos\theta,\cos\varphi\sin\theta,-\sin\varphi).$$

**Q1)** How can I compute $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ for $i,j,k\in\{\varphi,\theta\}$. The thing I know is that $$g=\sin^2\varphi\mathrm d \theta^2+\mathrm d \varphi^2$$
and that $$\nabla _{\partial i}\partial _j=\sum_{k\in\{\theta,\varphi\}}\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial _k$$
where $i,j\in \{\theta,\varphi\}$. But to be honnest, I really don't know how to apply those formula to get Christoffel symbol. I recall that for example $\partial _\theta=\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}$.

**Q2)** An other thing I don't understand, it's with the definition of $\partial _\varphi$ and $\partial_\theta$ above, how will I compute for example $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}$ ? where $g$ is a function (for example, $g(\theta,\varphi)=\theta^2\varphi$) . How will I apply this ?

Comment: You can express all elements of the tangent space as a linear combination of $f_\phi$ and $f_\theta$, and then compute the first and second fundamental form as $Edu^2+2Fdudv+Gdv^2$ and $edu^2+2fdudv+gdv$ respectively, where $E,F,G,e,f,g$ are certain functions of $f_\phi$ and $f_\theta$. Does this sound familiar? Using this, there is some formula for the $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ in terms of $E,F,G,e,f,g$.

Comment: @lattice: thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, this is not familiar to me. What I know is that $$\Gamma_{ij}^k=\frac{1}{2}g^{k\mu}(\partial _i g_{\mu j}+\partial _j g_{\mu i}-\partial _\mu g_{ij}),$$ but still, I don't really know how it works...

Comment: Sorry, the parametrization $f$ and the function $f$ used for the second fundamental form is not the same. We usually denote the parametrization by $\chi$.

Comment: Hmm I just took a class in Differential Geometry and the way we learned was the one described above. It takes some time and a lot of calculations to prove these formulas, but afterwards they are easy to use I think. Sadly, I do not know the terms that you use (such as where the function $g$ comes from or what is $\partial_\varphi$), so I cannot help you with that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
g_{\theta\theta}=\sin^2\varphi ~~~~~~ g_{\varphi\varphi}=1 ~~~~~~other=0
$$
Then,only $\partial_\varphi g_{\theta\theta}=\sin 2\varphi$ , other $\partial g =0$.
By $\Gamma_{ij}^k=\frac{1}{2}g^{k\mu}(\partial _i g_{\mu j}+\partial _j g_{\mu i}-\partial _\mu g_{ij})$, have
$$
\Gamma^\theta_{\varphi\varphi}=0   \\
\Gamma^\theta_{\theta\varphi}=\Gamma^\theta_{\varphi\theta}=\frac{\sin 2\varphi}{2\sin^2\varphi}  \\
\Gamma^\varphi_{\theta\theta}=\frac{\sin 2\varphi}{2}  \\
\Gamma^\varphi_{\theta\varphi}=\Gamma^\varphi_{\varphi\theta}=0
$$

When you compute the $\Gamma$ , it is just complex, don't be afraid. Riemannian geometry always be  complex . Just my opinion ,and I am beginner too.